# Photoshop layers converting to background layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Everytime I open a new layer in Photoshop and add an image, it reverts back to a background layer with that image in the thumbnail: (1)I have unlocked the layer and renamed it, clicked to confirm before adding the image to the layer (2) I have added layers above it, then binned the background layer before adding my image to the top layer. It always reverts back to a locked background image, with the new image reflected in the background thumbnail. I have spent days on this on PS help pages, google and YouTube, and now am very behind on a project! Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce the problem. Can you please list the exact steps you are doing?  When you say you "open a layer", what do you mean? Are you adding a new layer, are you pasting an image, are you placing an image, are you opening a new image, clicking and dragging an image?  When you say you have added layers above, how are you then adding an image? paste? place? clicking and dragging a file? When you open a new image in Photoshop, the background layer will be locked by default. Is that what you are talking about?